# spark Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits

Tags: apache-spark

I'm running spark in AWS EMR.
it's a simple computation of PageRank, dataset is 8GB

I use 6 m3.xlarge for my cluster,each 16GB memory

here is the configuration

```
spark.executor.instances   4
spark.executor.cores       8
spark.driver.memory    10473M
spark.executor.memory   9658M
```

I'm new to Spark, so I really have no common sense about how memory-consuming it's......Is my cluster too small?  And is the memory a hard limit? or , small memory is ok but just computing slow....

here is my code (in our homework we're not allowed to use GraphX, so I just use plain function)

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD;

object PageRank {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("pageRank")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val iterNum = 10
    val file = sc.textFile("hdfs:///input")


    val all = file.flatMap { line => line.split("\t") }.distinct()
    val contributor = file.map ( line => line.split("\t")(0)).distinct()
    val dangling = all.subtract(contributor)

    val graphDangling = dangling.cartesian(all).groupByKey()

    val graph0 = file.map(line => { val temp = line.split("\t"); (temp(0), temp(1)) }).distinct().groupByKey()
    val graph = graph0.union(graphDangling)
    graph.cache()

    var ranks = graph.mapValues { x => 1.0 }

    var i = 0

    for (i <- 0 to iterNum) {
      val contriReceive = graph.join(ranks).values.flatMap {
        case (followees, rank) =>
          {
            val size = followees.size;
            followees.map(followee => (followee, rank / size))
          }
      }
      ranks = contriReceive.reduceByKey(_ + _).mapValues { x => 0.15 + 0.85 * x }
    }

    val result = ranks.map{case(user,rank)=>user+"\t"+rank}

    ranks.saveAsTextFile("hdfs:///pagerank-output")

    sc.stop()
  }

}
```

I'm not very sure about the RDD and memory management. There are many intermediate RDD, do i have to explicitly release them to free the resource? if so, how to ....just assign to null and gc will deal with it?

Comment: First of all, m3.xlarge has 15G memory, not 16G. Secondly, you should probably at least increase memoryOverhead to say 2G. Also, I'm wondering which version of Spark you are using? You are doing some heavy operations with the cartesian product and several `groupByKey`, which will slow down you job a lot. In fact, `groupByKey` is often discouraged all together (see [here](https://blog.knoldus.com/2015/06/19/shufflling-and-repartitioning-of-rdds-in-apache-spark/)), so consider replacing that with `reduceByKey` instead.

Comment: I replace the groupByKey, it improved a lot! But still stuck at some stage....But the cartesian product seems inevitable...in my case, because there are some dangling user who didn't follower anyone, so I have to distribute they rank score to everyone otherwise the total ranks score will decrease in the iteration.

Comment: Well, I don't know which stage i stuck at ........the computation in the loop seems ok, so maybe it stuck in the previous stage

Comment: You can look in the UI to see the stages